# Prove that $\sqrt{ \frac{2x^2 - 2x + 1}{2} } \geq \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}$ for $0 < x < 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that

$$\sqrt{ \frac{2x^2 - 2x + 1}{2} } \geq \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}$$
for $0 < x < 1.$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{ \frac{2x^2 - 2x + 1}{2} }=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(2x-1)^2+1} \geq\frac{1}{2}\geq \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}$$
since over $(0,1)$ we have:
$$ x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2 $$
by AM-GM.

Comment: The last inequality is more simply shown to be true by $x-2+\frac1{x} = (\sqrt{x}-1/\sqrt{x})^2$. Otherwise, a very nice proof.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-x+\frac12}$,for which we have $f'(\frac12)=0$ and that $f'(x)<0$ for $0<x<\frac12$, while $f'(x)>0$ for $\frac12<x<1$. Therefore minimum of $f(x)$ on $0<x<1$ happens at $x=\frac12$, which is $f(\frac12)=\frac12$.

Now define $g(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$. Since $g'(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}>0$ for $0<x<1$, $g(x)$ s increasing on $0<x<1$, hence $g(x)\leq g(1)=\frac12$. That is $$g(x)\leq \frac 12\leq f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the function $\sqrt(x)$ is increasing so in order to prove your inequality it suffices to prove that:
$$
\frac{2x^2-2x+1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{x})^2}
$$
Also notice that on the domain $0<x<1$ we have $(x+\frac{1}{x})^2 > 0$ so the prove the previous inequality we need to show that:
$$
\frac{2x^2-2x+1}{2} \cdot (x+\frac{1}{x})^2 = x^4 - x^3+\frac{5}{2}x^2-2x+2-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}\geq 1
$$
We have $x^2>0$ so multiplying by $x^2$ and rearranging gives:
$$
x^6 - x^5+\frac{5}{2}x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x-1/2\geq 0
$$

Now using Mathematica one can verify that the polynomial $x^6 - x^5+\frac{5}{2}x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x-1/2$ has one minimum on $[0, 1]$ at $x = \frac{1}{3}$ with minimum $\frac{250}{729}$. This proves the last inequality and by reversing the steps you can now also prove the original inequality.